# Gatsby: why does a.png work, but b.png returns Error: emitFile is required from module system?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm dabbling a bit with Gatsby.

I want to add an image to my page.

I use the following code:

```
<img src={require('./../images/a.png')} />
```

Result: a.png is shown

I change the a to b:

```
<img src={require('./../images/b.png')} />
```

It returns:

```
Module build failed: Error: emitFile is required from module system
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/[x]/stack/[x]/node_modules/file-loader/index.js:9:27)
    at Object.loader (/Users/[x]/stack/[x]/node_modules/url-loader/dist/index.js:76:19)

 @ ./src/pages/index.js 293:52-89
```

b.png exists and is an exact copy of a.png. Only the name has been changed.
I've been staring and googling for about a week now. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing require?

```
<img src={'../images/b.png'} />
```

P.S: I'm guessing you only have to go one folder up.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, once I passed b.png through tinypng, it started working. I have no idea why, but I guess during the copying process, it changed b.png. I have no idea how or why it works now.

Some further debugging: I created the png in Sketch. If I export something directly from Sketch (.png, .svg, doesn't matter), it doesn't work in Gatsby. If I pass it through tinypng or tinysvg, it works. Sketch must do something weird with the file